not able to deploy my react app on hostinger
I have connected my Hostinger hosting to GitHub, and it successfully locates the index.html file through .htaccess. However, it only renders the index.html file and not the entire application.
I want the entire application to be rendered properly, not just the index.html file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
